# isearch buffer greyed out/blurred after update to macOS 11.3

Tags: osx, isearch

I'm running Mac Port version of emacs 27.2 on macOS big sur. I recently updated to macos 11.3, and I'm having some strange behavior when I do a `C-s` search. In around 75% of instances, the entire buffer turns blurred-out/grey except for the search matches (see screenshot). It looks like the semi-transparent background macOS puts behind many objects (e.g., dock, spotlight search)

Even after I've exited isearch, the greyed background persists until I switch buffers and switch back, so it's quite annoying. I experience the issue on both integrated MacBook screen and external displays.

Things I've tried:

- Reducing transparency in macOS preferences
- Disabling spotlight search in macOS preferences
- updating from emacs 27.1 --> 27.2
- stripping down .emacs file

How can I fix this?

[image: blurred isearch background]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue with these steps:

1. uninstall of emacs,
2. upgrade to Xcode command line tools
3. re-install Mac ports emacs with `brew install emacs-mac`